# I Need some HTML / CSS assistance

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm working on a ebay template for a store, and I'm trying to make a sidebar, and this happens.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjKvD.png

The sidebar is on the right, how do i get it to position all the way up?

here's the html/css code.

http://pastebin.com/DwbHeTcD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make whatever div you have that encompasses the entire navigation bar `position: absolute`, and make sure it's the first thing in CSS, to make it nothing override it.

Comment: Doing that forces the sidebar to the LEFT, even though I have float:right, but it did bring it to the top, so any ideas of how to get to to float 2 the right now?

Comment: Dont worry, I moved my sidebar div, above the description div, and it fixed it.